# Rails: list Conversation.users, if multiple user_ids stored in multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

How do I list all the users associated with `Conversations` if they're stored in different columns.

i.e, how do I call `c.users` and get `[#<User id: 1>, #<User id: 2>]` for the example below.

Class:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :initiator_id
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :recipient_id
end
```

Testing it out:

```
>> c = Conversation.first
>> c.initiator_id
=> 1
>> c.recipient_id
=> 2
>> c.user
=> #<User id: 2> # This only lists one user
> c.users
NoMethodError: undefined method `users'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two associations and use them like:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :initiator, foreign_key: :initiator_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  def users
    [initiator, recipient]
  end
end
```

Not sure if it's a good way but you can achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a subquery

```
SELECT 
conversations.id AS conversation_id,
initiator_id AS user_id
UNION
SELECT 
conversations.id AS conversation_id,
recipient_id AS user_id
```

which will give you a relationship between users and conversations directly.  If you're doing this frequently you could create it as a view so that you can query this table directly in Activerecord.

The whole query is

```
SELECT conversations_users.user_id
FROM 
  (SELECT 
  conversations.id AS conversation_id,
  initiator_id AS user_id
  UNION
  SELECT 
  conversations.id AS conversation_id,
  recipient_id AS user_id) conversations_users
WHERE conversations_users.conversation_id IN ?
```

Where you use the conversation_id with the appropriate value.
If you're doing this a lot, it makes sense to run a migration to create this as a view.
    def up

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW conversations_users_view AS
    SELECT 
conversations.id AS conversation_id,
initiator_id AS user_id
UNION
SELECT 
conversations.id AS conversation_id,
recipient_id AS user_id
SQL
end
```

Then you create a conversations_users active record model

```
class ConversationsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'conversations_users_view'
end
```

Then you can query it directly

```
users = ConversationsUser.where('conversations_id IN ?', c.id)
```